# C++ change lowercase to Uppercase using a dynamic array

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying to use a Dynamic Array to change a lowercase word into an uppercase word.  I ran into something I haven't encountered before called a "Heap Corruption".  Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong and possibly help fix this??

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <new>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i;
    int w;
    char *p;
    string str;

    cout << "Change lowercase to UPPERCASE!" << endl;
    cout << "Enter Word: ";
    cin >> str;
    w = str.length();

    p = new (nothrow) char[w];

    if (p == nullptr)
        cout << "Error: memory could not be allocated" << endl;
    else
    {
        cout << "Re-Enter Word: ";
        cin >> p[w];
        for (i = 0; i < w; i++)
            cout << static_cast<char>(toupper(p[i]));
        cout << endl;
    }

    delete[] p;

    cout << "Press <Enter> to Exit";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `std::string` instead of `char*`. This will make life much easier for you.

Comment: `cin >> p[w];` accesses `p` out of bounds.

Comment: You're only reading *one* character, and then writing it out-of bounds. Even if you "fix" the input  - `cin >> p` - `p` is one character too small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you made so many mistakes, but to just answer **your** question:

```
p = new (nothrow) char[w + 1];
```

this is so that we will have room for the null termination character ('\0')

and also use:

```
cin >>  p;
```

Answer (score 6):

There's no need to use `char*` for conversion to upper case. Instead you could use [std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) like here:

```
transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::toupper);
cout << str << endl;
```

**--- edit ---**
If, for whatever (academic) reason, you want to perform the conversion to upper case on a dynamically allocated `char` array, then you could still use `std::transform` for that.

However, as you see in the snippet below, you need to allocate one extra character for the trailing `\0`-char which signals end of string.

```
char* szStr = new char[w+1];
std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), szStr, ::toupper);
szStr[w]='\0';
cout << szStr << endl;
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it through dynamic arrays?  I'm trying to grasp the concept of pointers and dynamic memory.

Comment: I'll play around more with using transform.  I forgot about the \0.

Comment: @Podis:  The technique is the same regardless of where the variable resides.  The `transform` function doesn't care if the container is locally defined (stack) or dynamically allocated (heap) or automatic variable.